# Increasing space in ubuntu cloud instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Hi i had created a ubuntu cloud instance for about 8Gb.Now i require to increase the size to say 32Gb.Any idea how to proceed will be much helpful.

Comment: Do you mean the EBS space?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about downtime, you can take a snapshot from your EBS volume and create a new volume from this, specifying a larger EBS size and attaching it to another instance. Keep in mind that you may have to enlarge your file system on it, too.

A detailed description of this can be found [here](http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root).